# Work out if vertices can be "naturally" connected

Tags: python, scripting, vertices, geometry, mathematics

Given two vertices that are a part of one face, work out if they can be connected without creating weird geometry.
Example of vertices that can be naturally connected:
[image: cool]
Example of vertices that cannot be naturally connected:
[image: bad]

Comment: As in, will an edge between two vertices fully be on the face they are part of, or will it cross outside of a concave portion of the face?

Comment: @TheLabCat Precisely